# Translation of short lyrics

Tags: traduction, anglais, paroles-de-chanson

There is a French song by Sebastien Tellier titled 'L'amour et la violence'. I'd really like to know what it means and I'm looking for someone kind enough to do a translation of that as I don't speak French at all.

> Dis-moi ce que tu penses
>
> De ma vie
>
> De mon adolescence
>
> Dis-moi ce que tu penses
>
> J'aime aussi
>
> L'amour et la violence

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CV65tWCZALI

**EDIT (after the feedback)**

L'amour et la violence

The last line (L'amour et la violence), 'I also like love and violence' didn't seem right, although it makes sense as 'I like love and violence too', I just thought that there might be a subtle different interpretation of something in the lyrics as native speakers would understand it that would shed more light on what the singer means.

Comment: We can't give whole translations as answers on this site, but as it is short and simple, here it is : Tell me what you think ; Of my life;Of my teenage years ;Tell me what you think ; I also  like love and violence

Comment: Thank you! Are you sure that the 'I also like love and violence' is correct and it's not 'I like love AND violence too'?

Comment: I am fairly sure of it; 'I like love AND violence too' would be 'J'aime l'amour et aussi la violence' (without ambiguity). however you could translate it as 'I like love and violence, too.' (unless you do not agree that the comma is use so as to Apply 'too' to both nouns or to someone)

Comment: But why does he say that? Because if you look at the previous lines it doesn't make sense. Does this line seem to be out of context in French too?

Comment: I just read your edit, I'm a bit slow here. Looks like there should be a come there then, Thanks!

Comment: I'm as puzzled as you are; I also  asked myself, as he is talking to someone, whether he would not be refering to that person's liking for love and violence and saying that he too (the singer or rather the person whose mind he speaks ) is a lover of love and violence.

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand what is the problem. Google Translate or DeepL come in handy here:

> Tell me what you think
>
> Of my life
>
> Of my adolescence
>
> Tell me what you think
>
> I also like love and violence

Above is my attempt. Below, there is another translation from the site:

https://lyricstranslate.com/en/lamour-et-la-violence-love-and-violence.html

> Love and Violence
>
> Tell me what you think
>
> Of my life
>
> Of my adolescence
>
> Tell me what you think
>
> I like love and violence too
>
> Tell me what you think

Comment: I've been on that site and I've tried online translators too including google. But the last line didn't seem to fit in the context  and I was wandering if French people (or someone with good French) would interpret something differently as I'm trying to understand the song.

Comment: @Gab Which line?

Comment: @Gab I did a googling but I found but one site talking about this song and its meaning. Unfortunately, it is in French. https://www.senscritique.com/morceau/L_Amour_et_La_Violence/critique/50651480 You can go paragraph by paragraph by Google translate and if something doesn't make sense, you can post it as a question. Of course, this is not a most perfect solution but rather a workaround. (Btw, I suggest you lean French ASAP. It is an amazing language:-)!)

Comment: The last line, 'I also like love and violence' didn't seem right, although it makes sense as 'I like love and violence too', I just thought that there might be a subtle different interpretation of something in the lyrics as native speakers would understand it that would shed more light on what the singer means.I'm sure French is a nice language but I'm personally not interested. :)

Comment: @Gab : Having finished with the translation, I edited your question concentrating on the line that you are interested in. In this way, I think you will receive more feedback. Basically, FSE is not a translation site and normally one does not get translation from French into English (it works the other way but stil the question should be as precise as possible).

Comment: OK, thanks! I don't know this site, I was just looking for a French-English one with activity on it.

Comment: @Gab You are welcome! Should you want to receive as much feedback as possible (and to avoid question closing), take the tour of FSE before posting another question. It is rather simple and quick:-)! https://french.stackexchange.com/tour